# How can I formulate an acceptable question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have formulated several different versions of the question, each one simpler and simpler, but all of them got rejected. Can someone help me formulate a question that the moderators will accept? I have a deadline soon at work, and would really appreciate help. Here is my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484631/possible-to-work-with-several-dataframes-in-pandas?noredirect=1#comment41608371_26484631

First I asked "how can I do these three things, please give me some example code too". But that was rejected because it was too broad. Then I edited to "how can I do this single thing, please give some example code too". But that was rejected too because it was too broad. After several iterations I finally edited to "Is it possible to do this single thing?" but that got rejected too. I mean, how can a question that can be answered"yes/no" be considered too broad? What am I doing wrong? My deadline is not funny.

I would really appreciate some feedback here, so I can formulate a question so I can get help and reach my deadline.

Comment: So you would be entirely satisfied with someone posting an answer that said nothing other than, "yes it's possible" and providing no other information?  Your not actually interested in an explanation of how to actually accomplish what you're asking about?  That certainly doesn't sound very useful to me.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773

Comment: If you need to get expert advice on a deadline, you hire someone to provide that advice. Of course, you have to have started the search for an expert to hire waaaaaaay before the deadline approaches.

Comment: @gnat I don't think that dup-closing is necessarily appropriate to a "Help me write better questions" post.  Linking to it makes sense, but it seems that we should help the user write better questions if we can rather than just closing the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Joe do you mean this would better be treated as [meta-tag:specific-question]? in that case, dupe would be indeed inappropriate, linking would be enough

Comment: Yes, that would.

Comment: Servy, actually I first asked "how can I do this, and give me some code, and I need to tackle this aspect, and this and this". But that was too broad. Apparently I was not allowed to ask subquestions detailing my needs "I need the code to tackle this issue, and this". So I simplified further and further, and each got rejected being to broad. Finally I arrived at "yes/no" question - but that was too simple. So how do I ask a question that is not too broad, and not too simple? If I specify my needs with subquestions, I am too broad. Can you help me, so my question gets through "Edchum" et al?

Answer (score 13):

Orvar, you have a couple of basic issues here.

First off, your earlier few questions weren't exactly too broad, but what they were was asking for someone to do your work for you.  That's not what StackOverflow is for.

Then you simplified the question too much, to a yes/no question, which also isn't very useful: you don't want to know if something's possible, you want to know *how*, so how does "is it possible" really help?

What you want is a middle ground: a way to ask the question "how do I do..." without asking someone to do an entire project, effectively, for you.

The way you get there is to do as much of the work as you can, and then narrow down what your next step/need is so that you have just one small thing that you're asking about, and ask that question.  Maybe that's a fairly early question, but you should at least get to that point.

In this case, what I'd do is take the question you linked above, and add the code you use to bring just one of those in (if it's a lot of code, simplify it so it's obvious how you're doing it).  Your question is really, "I have this code that executes once.  How do I run this efficiently 20 times?", which is a reasonable question.  You're asking someone to show you one specific thing - how to generalize a single action - and that's reasonably answerable.

It's also reasonably applicable to others, which is a key element of StackOverflow: it's not a "help service", really, it's a database of how-to information.  Your question should be helpful to you, but it should also usually be helpful to other people who might have the same problem - hence why we want it to be pretty focused on one specific issue, and not "show me start to finish the whole thing".

Comment: No its not like that you describe. I was not asking someone to do the work for me. I was asking for sample code how to work with several dataframes at once. Obviously I need to adapt the sample code to my particular task.

I was asking something like "how can I do this, and can you provide me some code, in particular I wonder how to tackle this difficulty, and this, and this". But that question got rejected being too broad. 

So what was really the issue? I would like to know so I get help when I need to. And the issue was NOT asking someone to do the work for me, I already got my code working

Comment: How about this? "I am trying to do X, and I do X by reading in lot of different csv files into different dataframes. How can I generalize this to handle many more dataframes? Maybe by reading into one large dataframe? But in that case, how do I access each dataframe - can you give me some sample code?". This is EXACTLY what I wrote, but it got rejected being too broad. How would you reformulate this question?