# What do I do when someone downvotes a detailed question without explanation?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, asking-questions, downvote-reason

I recently asked a question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433183/make-scrollable-div-take-up-remaining-height)), and have not received any answers. I have put a lot of effort into providing all the detail that I can. However, it just received a downvote. How can I ask WHY so that I can improve my question and hopefully get answers instead of just downvotes?

Comment: You can ask by posting a comment below the question, but the downvoter is not obligated to respond, nor do they get a notification (since you don't know their user name).  Voting is anonymous by design, and the issue of explaining downvotes has been [discussed and debated exhaustively here on meta already](https://www.google.com/search?q=explaining%20downvotes%20site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: You move on. If your question is good enough, on the whole you'll get more upvotes than downvotes, in time. You can post a comment asking if anyone can point out what can be improved, but noone is obliged to explain.

Comment: If you follow @RobertHarvey's advice, please don't write "@downvoter please explain yourself". Something along the lines of "I seem to be receiving some downvotes. Is there anything I'm overlooking here which I could address?" would work better. Don't manoeuvre people into a corner. Given them a chance to help you out.

Comment: Yes, never write angry comments asking downvoters to explain their downvotes, it only attracts more downvotes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys! I'm not planning on writing anything angry, I just want to fix my question. I'm worried that if all I do is comment on my question, no one will see it because the question already has been downvoted. Is there a way to ask the broader SO community how to improve my question?

Comment: You can ask on MSO with tags [specific-question] and [question-quality], but don't write an angry post. Also, Monday is the best day to ask because not many people are online on weekends. Here is an example where a user asked about improving their question in a positive way http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275265/feedback-on-the-quality-of-this-question-about-a-runtime-error-in-a-small-functi

Comment: Useful reference http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274977/how-can-i-formulate-an-acceptable-question